# How to control the splitting and pushing data to mappers in Hadoop-streaming with python?

Tags: python, hadoop, hadoop-streaming

Given a data frame `df1` in following form:

```
u1_id    u2_id       
a1       a2       
a3       a5
a2       a4
...
```

And another data frame `df2` in following form:

```
u_id     p
1        (1, 2, 4, 10, 13, 14)
2        (5, 6, 12, 1, ...)
...
```

The `u1_id` and `u2_id` in the same row in `df1` are for pair-wise similarity measurement, and the `p` are the users' attribute. I'd like to split the job and send it to `n` mappers. Here are the detailed steps:

1. Split the `df1` into n pieces. For each one, the corresponding `p` of two users should be added to the `df1_n`. So it would be like this:

   ```
   u1_id    u2_id   u1_p                    u2_p
   a1       a2      (1, 2, 4, 10, 13, 14)   (5, 6, 12, 1, ...)
   a3       a5      (2, 3, 6)               (1, 3, 4, 8)
   a2       a4      (4, 6, 7, 8)            (1, 2, 3)
   ...
   ```

   And send it to one mapper.
2. The mapper just sends the data frame to the reducer.
3. The reducer measures the similarity. And the results are merged and sort.

The difficulty is I don't know how to send the data to the mapper manually. Could you please help me?